# 3-layered Neural network doesen't learn properly

Tags: neural-network

So, I'm trying to implement a neural network with 3 layers in python, however I am not the brightest person so anything with more then 2 layers is kinda difficult for me. The problem with this one is that it gets stuck at .5 and does not learn I have no actual clue where it went wrong. Thank you for anyone with the patience to explain the error to me. (I hope the code makes sense)

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def reduce(x):
    return x*(1-x)

l0=[np.array([1,1,0,0]),
np.array([1,0,1,0]),
np.array([1,1,1,0]),
np.array([0,1,0,1]),
np.array([0,0,1,0]),
]

output=[0,1,1,0,1]

syn0=np.random.random((4,4))
syn1=np.random.random((4,1))

for justanumber in range(1000):
    for i in range(len(l0)):

        l1=sigmoid(np.dot(l0[i],syn0))
        l2=sigmoid(np.dot(l1,syn1))

        l2_err=output[i]-l2
        l2_delta=reduce(l2_err)

        l1_err=syn1*l2_delta
        l1_delta=reduce(l1_err)

        syn1=syn1.T
        syn1+=l0[i].T*l2_delta
        syn1=syn1.T

        syn0=syn0.T
        syn0+=l0[i].T*l1_delta
        syn0=syn0.T
        print l2
```

PS. I know that it might be a piece of trash as a script but that is why I asked for assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your computations are not fully correct. For example, the `reduce` is called on the `l1_err` and `l2_err`, where it should be called on `l1` and `l2`.
2. You are performing stochastic gradient descent. In this case with such few parameters, it oscilates hugely. In this case use a full batch gradient descent.
3. The bias units are not present. Although you can still learn without bias, technically.

I tried to rewrite your code with minimal changes. I have commented your lines to show the changes.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def reduce(x):
    return x*(1-x)

l0=np.array ([np.array([1,1,0,0]),
np.array([1,0,1,0]),
np.array([1,1,1,0]),
np.array([0,1,0,1]),
np.array([0,0,1,0]),
]);

output=np.array ([[0],[1],[1],[0],[1]]);

syn0=np.random.random((4,4))
syn1=np.random.random((4,1))
final_err = list ();
gamma = 0.05
maxiter = 100000
for justanumber in range(maxiter):
    syn0_del = np.zeros_like (syn0);
    syn1_del = np.zeros_like (syn1);
    l2_err_sum = 0;
    for i in range(len(l0)):
        this_data = l0[i,np.newaxis];

        l1=sigmoid(np.matmul(this_data,syn0))[:]
        l2=sigmoid(np.matmul(l1,syn1))[:]

        l2_err=(output[i,:]-l2[:])
        #l2_delta=reduce(l2_err)
        l2_delta=np.dot (reduce(l2), l2_err)

        l1_err=np.dot (syn1, l2_delta)
        #l1_delta=reduce(l1_err) 
        l1_delta=np.dot(reduce(l1), l1_err)

        # Accumulate gradient for this point for layer 1
        syn1_del += np.matmul(l2_delta, l1).T;
        #syn1=syn1.T
        #syn1+=l1.T*l2_delta
        #syn1=syn1.T

        # Accumulate gradient for this point for layer 0
        syn0_del += np.matmul(l1_delta, this_data).T;
        #syn0=syn0.T
        #syn0-=l0[i,:].T*l1_delta
        #syn0=syn0.T

        # The error for this datpoint. Mean sum of squares
        l2_err_sum += np.mean (l2_err ** 2);

    l2_err_sum /= l0.shape[0]; # Mean sum of squares
    syn0 += gamma * syn0_del;
    syn1 += gamma * syn1_del;

    print ("iter: ", justanumber, "error: ", l2_err_sum);
    final_err.append (l2_err_sum);


# Predicting
l1=sigmoid(np.matmul(l0,syn0))[:]# 1 x d * d x 4 = 1 x 4;
l2=sigmoid(np.matmul(l1,syn1))[:] # 1 x 4 * 4 x 1 = 1 x 1

print ("Predicted: \n", l2)
print ("Actual: \n", output)

plt.plot (np.array (final_err));
plt.show ();
```

The output I get is:

```
Predicted: 
 [[0.05214011]
 [0.97596354]
 [0.97499515]
 [0.03771324]
 [0.97624119]]
Actual: 
 [[0]
 [1]
 [1]
 [0]
 [1]]
```

Therefore the network was able to predict all the toy training examples. (Note in real data you would not like to fit the data at its best as it leads to overfitting). Note that you may get a bit different result, as the weight initialisations are different. Also, try to initialise the weight between `[-0.01, +0.01]` as a rule of thumb, when you are not working on a specific problem and you specifically know the initialisation.

Here is the convergence plot.[image]

Note that you do not need to actually iterate over each example, instead you can do matrix multiplication at once, which is much faster. Also, the above code **does not** have bias units. Make sure you have bias units when you re-implement the code.

I would recommend you go through the Raul Rojas' [Neural Networks, a Systematic Introduction](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/rojas/neural/neuron.pdf), Chapter 4, 6 and 7. Chapter 7 will tell you how to implement deeper networks in a simple way.

Comment: Ok I get it now, but thank you so much for your time and for this well detailed comment, i'll be sure to check the book :)